# Using dplyr in a function in R, and then a for loop to carry out the function

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dplyr

I have a dataframe, lets call it df1, that looks something like this:

```
product_key              month    price     productage

00020e32-8ecd53a64715   201508  65.00000    1
00020e32-8ecd53a64715   201509  65.00000    2
00020e32-8ecd53a64715   201510  65.00000    3
000340b8-60fb50bacac8   201504  55.00000    1
000340b8-60fb50bacac8   201505  55.00000    2
000340b8-60fb50bacac8   201506  53.16667    3
000340b8-60fb50bacac8   201507  27.50000    4
000340b8-60fb50bacac8   201508  27.50000    5
000340b8-60fb50bacac8   201509  27.50000    6
000340b8-60fb50bacac8   201510  27.50000    7
000458f1-9304a2fdb6ae   201506  49.00000    1
000458f1-9304a2fdb6ae   201507  49.00000    2
000458f1-9304a2fdb6ae   201508  49.00000    3
000458f1-9304a2fdb6ae   201509  49.00000    4
000458f1-9304a2fdb6ae   201510  49.00000    5
```

What I want to do is filter out all of the products that have been in the dataset for 1 month (e.g. `filter(productage ==1)`) and then create a Unit Value Index from those items and their prices. Then I want to do the same for products that have been in the dataset for 2 months and then 3 months and so on...

What I have done so far, but is long-winded is:

**MONTH 1**

```
df1month1 <- df1 %>%
filter(productage == 1)
```

**MONTHLY AVERAGES OF PRICES PER PRODUCT**

```
df1_UVIMONTH1<-df1month1%>%
  group_by(month)%>%
  summarise(aveprice=mean(price))
```

**UVI of MONTH 1,**
**calculating UVI price indices**

```
  df1UVIMONTH1<-df1_UVIMONTH1%>%
  mutate(month=as.numeric(month))%>%
  arrange(month)%>%
  mutate(UVI=(aveprice/lag(aveprice)))%>%
  mutate(UVI=case_when(month==min(month)~1,
                       month!=min(month)~ UVI))%>%
  mutate(chained=cumprod(UVI))
```

However, to do this for each product age within the dataset (there can be up to 26) and for 10 different datasets is long and tedious. I'm trying to make this process more efficient but am struggling.

I've attempted to create a function:

```
product_by_age <- function(df1, age){
  filter_by_month <- df1 %>%
    filter(productage %in% age) %>%
    group_by(month) %>%
    summarise(aveprice=mean(price))

  UVI_index <- filter_by_month %>%
    mutate(month=as.numeric(month))%>%
    arrange(month)%>%
    mutate(UVI=(aveprice/lag(aveprice)))%>%
    mutate(UVI=case_when(month==min(month)~1,
                         month!=min(month)~ UVI))%>%
    mutate(chained=cumprod(UVI))
}



df1productage <- data.frame(age = unique(df1$productage), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

result <- data.frame()
for (i in df1productage:length(df1productage)) {
  sba <- product_by_age(df1, df1productage[i])
  result <- rbind(result, sba)
}
```

But it's not working for me. Please help! If anyone can think of a better way to approach this then let me know. I don't mind if you completely redo the function, either.

To recreate my sample dataset you can use:

```
product_key <- c(“00020e32-8ecd53a64715”, “00020e32-8ecd53a64715”, ”00020e32-8ecd53a64715”, “000340b8-60fb50bacac8”, “000340b8-60fb50bacac8”, “000340b8-60fb50bacac8”, “000340b8-60fb50bacac8”, “000340b8-60fb50bacac8”, “000340b8-60fb50bacac8”,   “000340b8-60fb50bacac8”, “000458f1-9304a2fdb6ae”, “000458f1-9304a2fdb6ae”, “000458f1-9304a2fdb6ae”, “000458f1-9304a2fdb6ae”, ”000458f1-9304a2fdb6ae”)
month <- c("201508", "201509", "201510", "201504", "201505", "201506", "201507", "201508", "201509", "201510", "201506", "201507", "201508", "201509", "201510")
price <- c("65", "65", "65", "55", "55", "53.16667", "27.5", "27.5", "27.5", "27.5", "49", "49", "49", "49", "49")
productage <- c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
df1 <- data.frame(product_key, month, price, productage)
```

Comment: ... `group_by(productage, month) `...?

Comment: I think the mistake is in `df1productage:length(df1productage`

Comment: @Tjebo it doesn't work because you'd have all product ages within one dataset and so you'd have to add in some sort of filter function at that stage, too, to get the result you wanted. Which would again mean changing the filter function to filtering by each product age - which is long and tedious.

Comment: Also, inside the function `price_currentdaymode` is there which is not in the input dataset.  Your example for numeric columns should be without quotes.  It creates `factor` or `character` class based on this

Comment: @akrun - i've updated that, that's what the price variable is called in my dataset but changed it to price for ease in this example. I created a dataframe called df1product age with all unique product age values in, so thought that would work. I can't see why it's not?

Comment: @JayJ Thanks, yes it is working now.  Please check the solution posted below

Comment: Sorry, I might have simply misunderstood your question. A desired output would have helped (me). I am always impressed how @akrun so easily understands what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with grouping, without new function!

```
require(dplyr)

df1%>%
  group_by(month, productage)%>%
  summarise(aveprice=mean(price)) %>% arrange(productage, month) %>%
    group_by(productage)%>%
    mutate(UVI=c(1, aveprice[2:length(aveprice)]/aveprice[1:length(aveprice)-1])) %>%
  mutate(chained=cumprod(UVI))

 ### Group and then regroup. and I have modified your mutate code which was using 'lag' 

# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   productage [7]
    month productage aveprice   UVI chained
    <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 201504 1              55.0 1.00    1.00 
 2 201506 1              49.0 0.891   0.891
 3 201508 1              65.0 1.33    1.18 
 4 201505 2              55.0 1.00    1.00 
 5 201507 2              49.0 0.891   0.891
 6 201509 2              65.0 1.33    1.18 
 7 201506 3              53.2 1.00    1.00 
 8 201508 3              49.0 0.922   0.922
 9 201510 3              65.0 1.33    1.22 
10 201507 4              27.5 1.00    1.00 
11 201509 4              49.0 1.78    1.78 
12 201508 5              27.5 1.00    1.00 
13 201510 5              49.0 1.78    1.78 
14 201509 6              27.5 1.00    1.00 
15 201510 7              27.5 1.00    1.00
```

Now you can simply use `split` in order to split by column productage

Comment: Thanks - this doesn't directly answer the question (for readers) but it does exactly what I want and makes my code a lot simpler and more efficient!

Answer (score 1):

We need change the loop a bit.  Assuming that we are looping through the sequence of rows in 'df1productage', and 'result' is initialized as a blank data.frame,

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df1productage))) {
    result <- rbind(result, product_by_age(df1, df1productage$age[i]))
 }

dim(result)
#[1] 15  4
```

---

Or using the `tidyverse` way

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(df1productage %>% 
              pull(age), ~    
                    product_by_age(df1, .x), .id = 'grp')
# A tibble: 15 x 5
#   grp   month aveprice   UVI chained
#   <chr> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 1         1     55   1       1    
# 2 1         3     49   0.891   0.891
# 3 1         5     65   1.33    1.18 
# 4 2         2     55   1       1    
# 5 2         4     49   0.891   0.891
# 6 2         6     65   1.33    1.18 
# 7 3         3     53.2 1       1    
# 8 3         5     49   0.922   0.922
# 9 3         7     65   1.33    1.22 
#10 4         4     27.5 1       1    
#11 4         6     49   1.78    1.78 
#12 5         5     27.5 1       1    
#13 5         7     49   1.78    1.78 
#14 6         6     27.5 1       1    
#15 7         7     27.5 1       1
```

EDIT: Added an identifier column within `map_df`

Comment: thank you! That works brilliantly (I have just used the dplyr way) - is there a way in which I could get separate data frames for each product age for my results? Or at least have the product age added in another column next to the Unit Value Index, and code this somewhere within the function, as currently I have index variables but it doesn't tell me which project age they correspond to. Thanks again

Comment: @JayJ, You can use `.id` within `map_df` i.e. `map_df(df1productage %>% ...), .id = 'grp')`